# How should I provide help for a related set of functions?

Tags: emacs

I built [tfs.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/tfs.el) to allow developers to do TFS things (checkout, checkin, etc) from within emacs.

There are 13 interactive commands in the tfs package, like `tfs/checkout`,  `tfs/rename`, `tfs/diff`, and so on, and I'd like to be able to provide help on all of them in a single place. An overview of all the available functions.

What's the "emacs way" of doing that?  I thought of defining an additional function, like `tfs/help` , that would invoke `describe-function-1` on each of the tfs functions, and then present all that in a TFS-Help buffer.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Regarding tfs, why not integrate it with Emacs' vc?

Comment: It was too intimidating for me to open that can o worms... I mean... to investigate that possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
    (describe-bindings "\C-xv")
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are many "Emacs way"s.

The most polished would be to write an *info* page, see the page ["Info for Experts"](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info/html_node/Expert-Info.html#Expert-Info), which basically says to use [Texinfo](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info/texinfo/index.html#Top) and convert that into an *info* page.  You can be as verbose as you want there, and the user can search, use hyperlinks, etc.  The user can easily get there via <kbd>C-h F tfs/checkout</kbd>.

Another way some folks seem to do it is to write short documentation strings for each of the commands, ending with "see documentation for `tfs-mode` for details" and put all the common documentation in the [docstring](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Documentation.html#Documentation) for tfs-mode.

Another way some packages document things is with a big comment at the top of the `tfs.el` file.

Take your pick, they all have trade-offs.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple, related commands. So far, I guess, they are related only by their names.

Two possibilities come to mind:

- Create a mode for this stuff. Document everything in the doc string of the command that turns the mode on/off.  It could be a major mode or a minor mode.  If a minor mode it could be buffer-local or global.
- Create a group (`defgroup`) for this stuff and document everything in its doc string.

The basic idea is to somehow actually *relate* these commands: bundle them together in some way, so you can document them together as the doc for the bundle.

Offhand, without knowing more, my guess is that you might want to create a global minor mode.

Comment: Minor mode sounds like the way to go. Also, maybe consider renaming the functions from `tfs/thing` to `tfs-thing` to better conform to Emacs conventions.

Comment: does this stuff really qualify as a minor mode?  These commands do not affect the editing of the current buffer, in the way that auto-fill does, or flymake does. The commands do operate on the current buffer. I'm not sure it rises to minor mode status.  Doesn't FEEL like a minor mode to me.  About the naming, I used `tfs/thing` because I liked the `yas/etcetc` naming on ya-snippet so much.